# Vim replace not matching multiple occurrences in one line

Tags: regex, vim

I need to replace all `foo` words with `bar`.

I tried with `:%s/foo/bar/g` But the issue is the `foo` occurs multiple times in one line, Only the first occurrence in each line is matched I have to run the command over again.

for example 
`:%s/"/'/g` on 
`"undefined"` only matches the first `"`

How can I match all occurrences in all lines?

Comment: Are you using neovim? In one of the versions this is actually broken.

Comment: Nope the same good old vim

Comment: Has you tried this with default vim, as in `vim -u NONE` and tried this. If it does work then try adding things to you vimrc until you beak it.